# How to obtain multiple solutions of a binary LP problem using Google's OR-Tools in Python?

Tags: python, linear-programming, or-tools, integer-programming, cp-sat

I am new to integer optimization. I am trying to solve the following large (although not that large) binary linear optimization problem:

max_{x} x_1+x_2+...+x_n

subject to: A*x <= b ; x_i is binary for all i=1,...,n

As you can see,

. the control variable is a vector x of lengh, say, n=150; x_i is binary for all i=1,...,n

. I want to maximize the sum of the x_i's

. in the constraint, A is an nxn matrix and b is an nx1 vector. So I have n=150 linear inequality constraints.

**I want to obtain a certain number of solutions, NS. Say, NS=100.** (I ***know*** there is more than one solution, and there are potentially millions of them.)

I am using Google's OR-Tools for Python. I was able to write the problem and to obtain one solution. I have tried many different ways to obtain ***more*** solutions after that, but I just couldn't. For example:

1. I tried using the SCIP solver, and then I used the value of the objective function at the optimum, call it V, to *add another* constraint, x_1+x_2+...+x_n >= V, on top of the original "Ax<=b," and then used the CP-SAT solver to find NS *feasible* vectors (I followed the instructions in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_tasks)). There is no optimization in this second step, just a quest for feasibility. This didn't work: the solver produced N replicas of the same vector. Still, when asked for the number of solutions found, it misleadingly replies that solution_printer.solution_count() is equal to NS. Here's a snippet of the code that I used:

```
# Define the constraints (A and b are lists)
for j in range(n):
    constraint_expr = [int(A[j][l])*x[l] for l in range(n)]
    model.Add(sum(constraint_expr) <= int(b[j][0]))

V = 112
constraint_obj_val = [-x[l] for l in range(n)]
model.Add(sum(constraint_obj_val) <= -V)


# Call the solver:
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solution_printer = VarArraySolutionPrinterWithLimit(x, NS)
solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = True
status = solver.Solve(model, solution_printer)
```

2. I tried using the SCIP solver and then using solver.NextSolution(), but every time I was using this command, the algorithm would produce a vector that was less and less optimal every time: the first one corresponded to a value of, say, V=112 (the optimal one!); the second vector corresponded to a value of 111; the third one, to 108; fourth to sixth, to 103; etc.

My question is, unfortunately, a bit vague, but here it goes: what's the best way to obtain more than one ***solution*** to my optimization problem?

Please let me know if I'm not being clear enough or if you need more/other chunks of the code, etc. This is my first time posting a question here :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your matrix A integral ? if not, you are not solving the same problem with scip and CP-SAT.

Furthermore, why use scip? You should solve both part with the same solver.

Furthermore, I believe the default solution pool implementation in scip will return all solutions found, in reverse order, thus in decreasing quality order.

Comment: Hi Laurent! First of all thanks so much for the amazing job you've done with OR-Tools.
Re: your questions:
1. Yes, A is integral: all the entries are integers.
2. I used scip just because this was the method I found in the guides (here: https://developers.google.com/optimization/mip/mip_example). I'm not sure whay you mean by "you should solve both parts with the same solver." In the second alternative (my point 2 above), I always used the SCIP solver, I didn't use CP-SAT.
3. How do I ask SCIP to return all solutions found? And what do you mean by solution here?

Answer (score 0):

In Gurobi, you can do something like this to get more than one optimal solution :

```cpp
solver->SetSolverSpecificParametersAsString("PoolSearchMode=2"); // or-tools [Gurobi]
```

From [Gurobi Reference](https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/plugins/hd_documentations/documentation/9.0/refman.pdf) [Section 20.1]:

> By default, the Gurobi MIP solver will try to find one proven optimal solution to your model.

> You can use the PoolSearchMode parameter to control the approach used to find solutions.
> In its default setting (0), the MIP search simply aims to find one
> optimal solution. Setting the parameter to 1 causes the MIP search to
> expend additional effort to find more solutions, but in a
> non-systematic way. You will get more solutions, but not necessarily
> the best solutions. Setting the parameter to 2 causes the MIP to do a
> systematic search for the n best solutions. For both non-default
> settings, the PoolSolutions parameter sets the target for the number
> of solutions to find.

Another way to find multiple optimal solutions could be to first solve the original problem to optimality and then add the objective function as a constraint with lower and upper bound as the optimal objective value.

Comment: Thanks whatchdos132, how can I use Gurobi in Python? Don't I need to buy a license in order to use it?

Comment: Yeah. But I think it is the same with SCIP also. You may need to find the equivalent of PoolSearchMode in SCIP.

Comment: ok Thanks! Maybe Laurent can help me with that ;)

Comment: Edited the answer. Could be of help. Thanks!